# Toolbar turns white (style/color not applied) in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-6.0-marshmallow

When we started testing our app on Android 6.0 devices the Toolbar (support action bar) is white. It's not using the colors we specified in the styles.xml. This has worked for all pre-marshmallow devices. Anyone knows why that might be? I couldn't find anything about it on Google.

Some code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.swekjaks.actionbartest.MainActivity">
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

tool_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
                               android:foreground="@color/white"
                               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/RelacomActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/RelacomActionBar</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="RelacomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: You're setting android:foreground="@color/white", so what color do you expect it to be?

Comment: Sweet. That worked. But why is it behaving like this? It's not very clear that the foreground is the background color of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the custom `styles` and `colors` to `styles.xml (v21)` as well and it will work fine.

[image]

The path for the `styles.xml (v21)` is:

```
\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it doesn't work. It's still white on Android 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug in the design library.
I'm using libraries 23.3.0. and the bug still occurs. 
Workaround for this is adding View that takes nearly no space and can be invisible. See the structure below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".3dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

this worked for me. let people know if it works for you. 
for more details please refer https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037